# Infinite sum of normalized Hermite polynomials

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, hermite-polynomials

Is it known any closed-form function of the infinite sum of the normalized probabilist's Hermite polynomials, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty  \frac{He_j(t)}{\sqrt{j!}}
\end{align}
where $He_j(t)$ is the probabilist's Hermite polynomial of degree $j \ge 0$. This was previously asked in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301779/normalized-probabilists-hermite-polynomial-sum) but not solved yet. Numerically, it seems to be converged to some deterministic function, but still unclear whether it indeed converges. Any comment or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!